# Multisite Redirect issue

Tags: multisite, redirect, wp-redirect

I had a working instance of multi-site wordpress running on version 3.4. I have upgraded this to 4.7. Everything seems to be working fine except that when I login to the sub-site it is redirecting me to the main site. This is happening for all the users other than admin.

Comment: I changed $url = network_site_url('wp-admin/user/', $scheme) to $url = network_site_url('wp-admin/', $scheme) on wp-includes/link-template.php:3372:  and made the sub_site variable dynamic from the current url in wp-config file. I know this not an ideal solution and would like to konw if somebody got it working without hacking.